# Set the max width of an image in tkinter

Tags: python, macos, image, tkinter, max

I know that in CSS you can set the maximum size of an image by using `max-width` and `max-height`. I want to do the same thing with tkinter. I've already tried using `Image.open("/path/to/file").resize(500)`, but I got the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root=Tk()
current_image=0
images=[ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("/users/27cadem/documents/display.png").resize(500))]

panel=Label(root,image=images[current_image])
panel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to provide the width and height in tuple form to `.resize()`.

Comment: You can use `PIL.Image.thumbnail()` to resize large image into specified width and height without changing the aspect ratio.  Image with size smaller than the specified width and height will not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

The code can be something like this:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
    
file = 'img-path.png'
    
image = Image.open(file)
    
max_width = 500
    
pixels_x, pixels_y = tuple([int(max_width/image.size[0] * x)  for x in image.size])
   
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.resize((pixels_x, pixels_y))) 
label = Label(root, image=img)
label.image = img
label.pack()
    
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).